# Making a function lazy in clojure

Tags: clojure, lazy-sequences

I have this function which seems to work fine on limited collections, but not on infinite ones. Is there a way to construct a `lazy-seq` in it to get it run with infinite coll's, like: `(take 3 (m inc (range)))` => `(1 2 3)`?

```
(defn m [f c] (reduce #(conj % (f %2)) [] c))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reduce` will keep taking elements from a sequence until `nil` gets returned. As such, `reduce` will never return on infinite sequences.

As pointed out in the comments, `reduced` can be used to force the termination of `reduce`, thanks!

Comment: Well, you can use `reduced` to terminate on infinite seqs.

Comment: This means put `reduce` inside an `if` expression?

Comment: Yes, you can check the examples over here: http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/reduced#example-542d2d0be4b05f4d257a2985

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a use case for `map`

```
(map f c)
```

or (when it had to be a vector)

```
(mapv f c)
```

**EDIT:**
A possible re-implementation of map:

```
(defn new-map [f coll]
  (if (seq coll)
    (lazy-seq
      (cons (f (first coll)) 
            (new-map f (rest coll))))))
```

Comment: I was trying to make something like `map`

Comment: So you want to re-implement map?

Comment: is it possible to use the `lazy-seq` on other expression bodies, like in my example? something like : `(defn m [f c] (lazy-seq (reduce #(conj % (f %2)) [] c)))
`

Comment: You can't use `reduce` to be lazy. When you "put" something `thing` in a lazy seq, then `thing` will not get lazy! It will remain the same. The laziness you get by using `lazy-seq` is the following: the `thing` in the seq will only be evaluate when you reach/look at `thing` in the seq.

The result of your function `m` is exactly the same as `(mapv f c)`

Comment: no, reduce is not lazy, it has to realize whole reduced collection. And wrapping it to lazy-seq won't help at all